# Split file in different records using a loop and give the files new names

Tags: sed, split

I have a large files (800.000 records) and I want to split this into different files of 20.000 records each. This one I can do, but my next problem is that I want to know if it's possible to automatically generate the new files?

Example: file1 contains 800.000 records. First I get 20000 records out of it and move to another file, and then I remove the `\r` characters.

```
sed -n '1,20000p;20001q'  file1 > file1_1
sed -e 's/\r//g' file1_1 > file1
```

Is it possible to do something in a loop? or do I have to write this 40 times?

The number of records is variable, today it contains 800.000 records, but tomorrow it can contain 789.123 of 812.321 records. Do I have to give an 'end number' with the sed-command?

Thank you all for your answers!!

Comment: Wait, so you only want to keep the first 20000 of each file?

Comment: No, I want all the records but split in files having 20000 records. Instead of having a file called xaa I want the file named file1 ; the next file not xab but file2 ; ...

Comment: OK, but the command you show simply takes the 1st 20000 lines and deletes everything else: `sed -e 's/\r//g' file1_1 > file1` will replace the contents of `file1` with the modified contents of `file1_1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Romeo Ninov already gave you [The Right Answer™](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498594/22222): use split. But to answer the general case about `sed`, you could do the same thing with:

```
i=1;
filelen=$(wc -l < file1)
while [[ $i -le $filelen ]]; do 
    sed -n "s/\r//;$i,$((i+19999))p;$(($i+20000))q;" file1 > file1.$i;
    ((i+=20000)); 
done
```

That saves each set of 20000 lines in a new file. If you really want to do what your question shows and only keep the 1st 20000 lines, it is much simpler:

```
sed -i 's/\r//; 200001q' file
```

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: @Katleen yay! But if one of the answers solved your issue (preferably Romeo's which gives the `split` solution), please take a moment to [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to split the file with command `split`. If you want 20k records in file the command will be:

```
split -l 20000 file1
```

If you want specific prefix for result files use command like:

```
split -l 20000 file1 PREFIX
```

If you want numeric suffixes for result files use command like:

```
split -d -l 20000 file1 PREFIX
```

Those commands will create bunch of files, splitted by 20k lines each.

To remove `^M` you can use loop like:

```
for i in PREFIX??
do
    dos2unix "$i" "${i}_unix"
done
```

This will add `_unix` on the end of files which have `^M` removed

Comment: FWIW with GNU `split`, the CR removal could be added as a filter e.g. `split -l 20000 --filter='sed "s/\r$//" > "$FILE"' file1 PREFIX`

Comment: that's an easy answer! And it works! Thank you so much, I thought it would me more difficult.
So right now I have 51 new files, but the name is like xaa till xby. Is it also possible to chose the name?

Comment: @Katleen, use my second example, this will make your files like PREFIXaa, PREFIXab and so on. Will add one more option to the answer :)